# sumif with matches between cells in the same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have columns A, B, C, and D

Column A and B have a list of names, bill bob, ricky, mike, etc.

Column C has numbers 1 - 200

Column D has numbers 1 - 4

I would like to sum the total from column C whenever there is a certain combination of names in columns A and B, and any number above 1 in column D.

Example: Whenever "Mike" is in column A, "Bob" is in column B, and any number above 1 is in column D, I would like to sum the total from C.

There will be multiple occurrences of the same combination, and I would like to sum the total for all occurrences of that combination.

I tried a sumif function, but it kept returning an error.

Comment: To clarify, since you mentioned that `"There will be multiple occurrences of the same combination"`, for example would having Bill on column A and Bob on column B in one row, and the opposite in another row (Bob on column A, Bill on column B) count as the same, hence 2 occurrences of the pair?

Comment: Thank you, yes, I should have been more clear. It doesn't matter which column the name is in, it can be in A or B as long as it's the same combo and there's a number greater than 1 in column D. Basically if there are three combos of Bill and Bob in columns A or B, and there's a number 2 in column D in the same row as the combos, I want to sum the total from C for all total occurrences.

Comment: Basically if there are three combos of Bill and Bob in columns A or B, there's the number 40 next to each combo in column C, and there's a number 2 in column D in the same row as the combos, I want to sum the total from C for all total occurrences. I want the formula to return "160" because it's 40 + 40 + 40.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying. I've just posted an answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C,(A:A="Andy")+(B:B="Andy"),(A:A="Bob")+(B:B="Bob"),D:D>1))
```

It first filters all numbers that satisfies all given conditions for a specific pair of names; this also covers name pairs that are interchangeable between the two columns. (see output below)

### OUTPUT

[image]